# When I try to download pictures from phone to computer, "no pictures found on this device"

Tags: usb-connection-mode, downloading

I have an LG-X Power. I have tried to download the pictures from my phone to my computer. When I connect through a USB cord - I receive a message on my computer that reads: "No pictures found on this device". The pictures are on my phone, there are many. I bought a new USB cord, still the same. I have a standard Windows operating system. 
I needed a few of the photos so I simply attached to an email, opened email on computer and downloaded that way. I have way too many to do that tedious method repeatedly. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have choose either PTP or MTP connection on phone. If still doesn't work than try this:
Go to settings>apps and find "media storage" and "external storage" (maybe you'll need to check "show system") clear data for both of them, and then reboot. After device boots wait up to 10 minutes for media database to update and connect phone via USB to PC.